# WPF ReactiveUI bindings in View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactiveui, rx.net

I'm creating a WPF application using Rx and ReactiveUI. Do I have to bind properties from the view in code behind reactively or is the classic way good?
I know binding between View and ViewModel objects, I just can't figure out if there should be a different way for these xaml bindings.

```xml
<Label x:Name="FilterLabel"
   ...
   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TemplateLabel}"
   .../>
```

Is this ok or is there a more "pro" way?

```cs
this.WhenActivated(d => {
    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Toolbar,   v => v.ToolbarView.ViewModel).DisposeWith(d);
});
```

This is how I do my ViewModel -> View bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply binding a view property to another in your Xaml, then in that case you're fine to stick with Xaml. But definitely stick to code-behind for View-ViewModel bindings, keeps your Xaml file cleaner and you also get the benefit of type-checking by using C# bindings.

Answer (score 2):

For view to view binding you can use following syntax inside your View code-behind:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.TemplateLabel.ActualWidth)
    .BindTo(this, view => view.FilterLabel.Width)
    .DisposeWith(disposable);
```

Answer (score 1):

XAML binding is fine for simple use cases, but for something more complex you defenitly should use code behind bindings, for example, code behind bindings gives you a selector function you can use this powerful feature to make your ViewModels simplier.

A little example:

```
this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {

            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.UserRole,
                v => v.UserRole.Text, GetAbreviatedRole).DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
```

In this case GetAbreviatedRole is a selector, that turns out saves you to use a value converter.

```
private string GetAbreviatedRole(string role)
    {
        if (role.Equals("SuperUser", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return "SU";
        if (role.Equals("BuildingManager", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return "BM";
        if (role.Equals("OfficeManager", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return "OM";
        if (role.Equals("OfficeManagerJunior", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return "OMJ";
        if (role.Equals("Usuario", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return "U";
        return "unknown";
    }
```

I hope this helps you.

Regards.

Comment: Also you can globally register converters for common types in your splat dependency injection which makes it super powerful when you got common types you want to convert between. Eg one registered by default is a Boolean to visibility converter so no more converters every time.